# How to read number by number from a line of numbers in an input file

Tags: java, arrays, input, integer

Basically I have to take an input file and fill out a array that is 9 by 9 but the input has to look like so

```
530070000
600195000
098000060
800006003
400803001
700020006
060000280
000419005
000080079
```

The numbers aren't separated but I need to take each and fill in the 9x9 array to make a Sudoku puzzle looking array. I can't figure out how to read the input number by number meaning the for the first line I would get 5 as the first int, then the next int would be 3, then 0, and so on.

```
public class SudokuChecker 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
   {
  
      File file = new File("in.txt");
      Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
     
      int [][] array = new int [9][9];

      while(in.hasNextLine()) 
      {
         for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) 
         {
            String[] line = in.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
          
            for (int j=0; j<line.length; j++) 
            {
               array[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(line[j]);
            }
         }
      }
   }  
}
```

[Board looks like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0vCY.png)

Comment: What have you tried in the "figure out"-phase?

Comment: I've just tried the basic while in.hasNextLine then in.nextInt to fill out the array, but it doesn't separate the line of numbers instead just making one of the values the 9 digits

Comment: One possible way is to split the input at space then you will get 9 big values so now convert each value toCharArray().

Comment: I'm not 100 % sure how the numbers are transformed into a sudoku. Could you draw the sudoku resulting from those numbers so it's crystal clear?

Comment: Chances are not zero that `.split(" ")` should be `.split("")`. Each number is on a seperate line, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that will read the current line and place the numbers in an 9x9 array. This only does it for each line and the array will be cleared subsequent line reads. OP will have to finish the code to handle subsequent line reads.

This utilizes `try-with-resource` and `BufferedReader` to read each line instead of Scanner. It will then read the line. Split the line on `space` then convert each item in the substring into the character array and iterate over them. It will then convert the value into an integer and store it into the array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  int[][] sudoku = new int[9][9];
  try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("in.txt"))) {
    String line = null;
    int row = 0;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      int col = 0;
      for (char c : line.toCharArray()) {
        sudoku[row][col++] = Integer.valueOf(Character.toString(c));
      }
      row++;
    }
  }
}
```